# Looping through an array of objects and find first item with position number

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-list

Ok, so I'm not sure how to word this but:

I have an array of albums, and each album has many images. I'm using the ruby gem `acts_as_list` to allow users sort the images in the albums, and thus each image has a position. And the way to do the sort is to set up between album images and non album images, not all albums will have an image with a position of one.

So, what I want to do is to list all albums, and then display only the image with the earliest position in that album. There is however, no method on position to find the first position.

Here is what I have now:

```
<% @albums.each do |i| %>
  <li class="box sortable_object" style="float:left; margin: 0.5em;" id="album_<%= i.id %>">
    <span class="handle">[drag me!]</span>
    <% unless i.tattoos.empty? %>
     <%= image_tag i.tattoos.first.file.url(:small) %><br />
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

But that simply finds the first image in the album based on its location in the image table, not its position number.

Comment: How come some albums do not have their lists start at 1? This should only happen if elements have been fiddled with manually. In the past, I've used a "re-order" method (patched onto acts_as_list) to re-number lists that have gotten out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify an `order` clause when declaring the association :

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tattoos, order: 'tattoos.position ASC'
end
```

This way, the first picture will aways be the one with lowest position.

Comment: you can alternatively do this in your `Tattoo` class: `default_scope order( arel_table[:position].asc )`

Comment: awesome thanks, I forgot I could set default orders on associations.

Comment: haha out of curiosity i just visited your tattoo site and totally rotfl'd about the hidden 'f**k IE' message

Comment: hahahahhaha yessssss. I was thinking about taking that down since I think I fixed the IE issues but now Im definitely leaving it up!